# VBA How to sum the levels?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to calculate in the Excel the total amount for a level. Quantity values and storm cost in sublevels. But when the loop reaches the next level, the flag changes, the function ends, but the loop starts again.I would like to get in C3 - 18,C9 - 20. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hz0r7kcnld598pkrpwi2a/test.xlsm?rlkey=709nzd6nd3p05g9ykf8k7zvgw&dl=0

```
Function CalculateSumBetweenLevels1(rng As Range, colQ As Range, colR As Range) As Double
Dim totalSum As Double
Dim cell As Range
Dim currentLevel As String
Dim dotPosition As Long
Dim isRootItem As Boolean

totalSum = 0
isRootItem = True

For Each cell In rng
    currentLevel = cell.Value
    dotPosition = InStr(1, currentLevel, ".")

    If dotPosition = 0 Then
        ' If the dot is not found, it's a root item
        If isRootItem = False Then
            ' If it's not the first root item, exit the loop
            Exit For
        Else
            ' Set the flag to False to indicate we've found a root item
            isRootItem = False
        End If
    End If

    ' Calculate the sum between levels
    totalSum = totalSum + cell.Offset(0, colQ.Column - cell.Column).Value * cell.Offset(0, colR.Column - cell.Column).Value
    
    Debug.Print "Result1: " & totalSum
Next cell

' Calculate the total sum for the root item
CalculateSumBetweenLevels1 = totalSum

End Function
```

I don't understand how I can end the loop and the function at the same time.
My  table
[image]

```
Debug shows: Result1: 0
Result1: 6
Result1: 8
Result1: 10
Result1: 16
Result1: 18
Result1: 0
Result1: 12
Result1: 14
Result1: 20
Result1: 0
Result1: 12
Result1: 14
Result1: 20
Result1: 0
Result1: 6
Result1: 8
Result1: 10
Result1: 16
Result1: 18
Result1: 0
Result1: 6
Result1: 8
Result1: 10
Result1: 16
```

I would like to stop and exit form for after - Result1: 18.

I am using fuction - [image]

Comment: `If totalSum = 18 Then Exit For` is an option for you?

Comment: No,is'it.I would like to calculate other line too.

Comment: I think, your problem is not in the function you show. Since `totalSum` is declared in local scope it is initially 0. If the loop starts again, it will increment the existing value... Please, show us how you use/call the function in discussion.

Comment: How are you calling this?  THIS code will not continue to run, and the `Exit For` is working.  You can see that someone is calling the function again from the beginning, because the sum starts again from 0.

Comment: =CalculateSumBetweenLevels1(A3:A23, $B$2:$B$23, $C$2:$C$23) I added the screenshot

Comment: If you call this function as UDF and it is placed in many cells, the function runs **FOR EACH SUCH A CELL**. Does the formula return the correct result in each cell where it exists? IF so, your `Debug.Print` code line means nothing. Only to confuse you... It was good only on testing period, to check how/if the function works. If you imagine that the above function works once **for all cells with it as UDF function formula**, this supposition is wrong.

Comment: This is an [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You ask about "how to end the loop" but your actual problem is "how to sum the levels". Please [edit] your quesition and add more information about your actual problem. Give an example of data and explain what exactly you want to sum up and what the results are that you expect for the example data.

Comment: Thanks, you are right.But how should i change the function?

Comment: Could you post an example of expected output?

Comment: Who is right? Do you know what tagging someone means? If the function is not designed by you and you try addressing to me, it is enough to comment/delete the `Debug.Print  "Result1: " & totalSum`. This code line was important only for Debugging purpose, when the function was designed. Now, only creates strange questions and strange return in `Immediate Window`. And do it each time `Calculate` event is triggered...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns
 I understand that the formula does not stop and continues to work until it reaches the end of the range. Intermediate results are correct. I would like to get in C3=18 (2*3+1*2+2*1+3*2+2*1),C9=20 (6*2+1*2+2*3)   https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hz0r7kcnld598pkrpwi2a/test.xlsm?rlkey=xdwmahxavfc3noj7fcpgd1iup&dl=0

Comment: @FaneDuru I know this, but at the same time it’s so much clearer what is happening in general, because. in the table cell the result is 0

Comment: I cannot get you... What Table? Do you mean the cell where the function returns? And need to see what's happening? If lo, I think the zero case is the simplest one... Only such a message will be displayed. Finally, if you understood that what you see in `Immediate Window` is normal to happen and **you want keeping that line**, what else do you expect when asking "how should i change the function"?

Comment: @FaneDuru  I see the desired result, but I cannot save it to a cell, because cycle does not stop

Comment: Is the range to be processed by the function really huge? Did you try (only for testing reason) to comment the line I suggested? Please, clear the C:C column and use the above function for only a cell. Does it return what you need? Then, for two cells. Does it return correctly in these two cells? With or without the mentioned `Debug.Print` code line. All my comments assumed that your function is correct. Now, can you explain what "he total amount for a level" means? **In words, with examples**. I do not see in your function an argument for level...

Comment: What a level is for you? Are 1.1 and 1.2 different levels?

Comment: @FaneDuru 1 and 2

Comment: I cannot get you...  You do not see in the picture so named "different levels". Your function does not take in consideration anything related to the cell calling the function. How do you expect/want it to return the levels total count? Please, show a picture with existing situation (but showing more than a case per level) and another one with the **desired output**.

Comment: @FaneDuru https://i.stack.imgur.com/wea0f.png

Comment: I do not understand anything! In what column **is** the returned/wanted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already detects the levels, you just need to calculate the grandtotal for current level. You can do this easily with SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

For this formula to work you must make sure your `lvl` values are being recognized as text and not numbers.

Formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A4:$A$12;LEN(A3)+1)=A3&".")*$B4:$B$12*$C4:$C$12)
```

You just need use the macro recorder to see how to input this formula into VBA, code it, paste values and done.

Comment: Why do you need that `--` there and not just `=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A4:$A$12,LEN(A3)+1)=A3&".")*B4:$B$12*C4:$C$12)`?

Comment: I don't fully understand how I can do this. This is my first experience with VBA. I tried changing my formula like this:

       ``` 
Calculate the total sum for the root item using the SUMPRODUCT formula
         Dim formulaString As String
         formulaString = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(" & rng.Address & "," & 
         Len(currentLevel) + 1 & ")=""" & currentLevel & """)," & colQ.Address & "," & 
          colR.Address & ")"
          CalculateSumBetweenLevels1 = Application.Evaluate(formulaString)  
```

I still get null on function exit

Comment: @DenisMurashko Actually you don't need VBA to do this. You can just put the formula in C3 and then copy C3 to C9. And it should show 18 and 20 if the sheet's data is exactly what is shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The problem is that I don't know what lines the root lvl will be in, so I need to fill in all the cells with a formula and then some of these cells will be filled with values ​​for the calculation.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Could you please show how did you do that?

Comment: @ I got that habit of typing it like that, there is not real reason

Comment: @DenisMurashko I don't understand what you mean with *how did you do that*. The formula is in the answer. You just need the VBA version for it and that can be obtained using the macro recorder